# Laravel Mailable not finding my aliased views when developed inside a package

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, eloquent

My SSH service provider loads views and aliases them to `ssh`.

```
public function boot()
{
    ...
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/views', 'ssh');
    ...
}
```

Inside of my `Mail` directory, I then have a test mail I'm using for debugging purposes as my service provider also has a scheduler running and I want to email after it executes. It looks like this:

```
class DockerTest extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private User $user;
    private Vps $vps;

    public function __construct(User $user, Vps $vps)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->vps  = $vps;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('ssh:mail.test', [
            'user' => $this->user,
            'vps'  => $this->vps
        ]);
    }
}
```

However, when ever I try to test this email in `php artisan tinker` like so:

```
Mail::to('foo@bar.com')->send(new DockerTest(($vps = Vps::find(1)), $vps->user))
```

I am hit with an exception

> InvalidArgumentException with message 'View [ssh:mail.test] not found.'

I load my routes like so in the `boot` function of my service provider:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../Http/routes.php';
```

When I then do this inside that folder:

```
Route::get('/test', function() { return view('ssh:mail.test', [($vps = Vps::find(1)), $vps->user]); });
```

It works perfectly fine? Any ideas? I am developing this as a package and my directory layout looks like this:

```
app
boostrap
...
packages
    MyPackage
        Ssh
            src
                Providers
                    SshServiceProvider.php
                Http
                    Routes.php
                Resources
                    views
                        mail
                            test.blade.php
                Mail
                    DockerTest.php
                database
                    migrations
                        ...
...
vendor
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your view loader.
when you load view in the package , you should write two colons like this:

```
return view('ssh::mail.test')
```